# Remove all min.css files from directory with Gulp

Tags: gulp

I am completely new to gulp, and while I have managed to implement some cool tasks wit gulp, I am having trouble implementing a task that will clear files matching specic pattern from specified directory.

In this particular case I would like to remove all files matching pattern '*.min.css' from css dir.

Here is a piece of code that deletes all files including directory, which is wrong. I want to remove only min.css files

```js
var gulp = require("gulp"),
  rimraf = require("rimraf"),
  concat = require("gulp-concat"),
  cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
  uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  rename = require('gulp-rename'),
  del = require('del');


var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.cssMinOutputPath = paths.webroot + "css";

gulp.task("clean:min.css", function (cb) {
    del([paths.cssMinOutputPath, "*.min.css"], cb);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was keep playing around, and magically I have resolved the issue. It makes sense though. Here is the snippet:

```js
gulp.task("clean:min.css", function (cb) {
    del([paths.cssMinOutputPath + "/*.min.css"], cb);
});
```